# Несколько параметров в функции jquery

Tags: jquery, javascript

Добрый вечер. Есть функция на jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.popup-gallery').magnificPopup({
        delegate: 'a',
        type: 'image',
        mainClass: 'mfp-img-mobile',
        gallery: {
            enabled: teByImgClick: true,
            rue,
            navigatpreload: [0,1] 
        },
        image: {
            tError: '<a href="%url%">The image #%curr%</a> could not be loaded.',
        }
    });
});
```

Можно ли как-то в этом участке указать несколько классов?

```
$('.popup-gallery').magnificPopup({
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вас это интересует, что ли?

```
$('.popup-gallery, .popup-gallery-2, .popup-gallery-3')
```

Comment: Благодарю.

Answer (score 0):

А ещё лучше:

```
var $popupGallery = $('.popup-gallery, .popup-gallery-2, .popup-gallery-3');
$popupGallery.magnificPopup({ /*...
```